# Arduino загрузчик мапит память?

Tags: arduino

`Arduino` загрузчик мапит память?

Когда из запущенной программы я работаю с памятью – это уже не прям голая RAM? Если да – есть ли способ перемапить память без прошивки загрузчика?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, загрузчик Arduino не маппит память.

Маппить память - так называется процесс отображения файла в оперативную память компьютера. Программа как бы обращается к виртуальной памяти, а на самом деле читает и записывает данные в файл. Это один из способов организации так называемой виртуальной памяти.

В микроконтроллере Arduino данные хранятся в оперативной памяти, размером всего 2 КБайта, но чтобы маппить память, нужно чтобы ядро микроконтроллера умело это делать. Для этого процессор AVR должен был бы поддерживать многопоточность, что например умеют процессоры, совместимые с Intel 80386.

Comment: Я думаю, автор под "маппить память" имеет в виду отображение части адресов на флешь (на плате), в которую изначально прописывается код программы.

Comment: @avp, он правильно понял мой вопрос.